# mongodb sum specific field in all documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I'm MongoDB beginner.
This is my cargo data:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("613f21a7c78e4d569474120a"),
        "cargoType" : "palletized",
        "description" : "fdsfdsfs",
        "price" : 666,
        "weight" : null,
        "height" : null,
        "width" : null,
        "clength" : null,
        "date" : ISODate("2021-09-13T10:02:15.000Z"),
        "userId" : ObjectId("60868c31caafe530e7e2d04a"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

This is my pallet data:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("613f21a8c78e4d569474120c"),
        "cargoWeight" : 8,
        "palletType" : "euro",
        "palletName" : "",
        "palletHeight" : 40,
        "palletWidth" : 300,
        "palletLength" : 40,
        "cargoId" : ObjectId("613f21a7c78e4d569474120a"),
        "__v" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("613f21a8c78e4d569474120d"),
        "cargoWeight" : 10,
        "palletType" : "euro",
        "palletName" : "",
        "palletHeight" : 50,
        "palletWidth" : 99,
        "palletLength" : 50,
        "cargoId" : ObjectId("613f21a7c78e4d569474120a"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

I want to calculate `palletWidth` for all documents(pallets) and then use it after as a new field. Something like that:

```
    const cargoQuery = Cargo.aggregate([
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: Pallet.collection.name,
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "cargoId",
              as: "pallets"
            }
          },
          { $addFields: {
            maxLineWidthEuro: { $sum : "$pallets.palletWidth"}
          }},
```

This is the place where I want to use `maxLineWidthEuro`:

```
    $match: {
            $or: [
      
              {cargoType: {$eq: cRulePALLETIZED}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$totalPalletsWeight", 0.98]}, tRuleMaxWeightPALLETIZED]}, maxLineWidthEuro: {$lte: totalWidth} },
              
            ],
```

So my `maxLineWidthEuro` should be `399`. Thank you for your time.

This is the whole query:

```
const cargoQuery = Cargo.aggregate([
      {
      $lookup: {
        from: Pallet.collection.name,
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "cargoId",
        as: "pallets"
      }
    },
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": Pallet.collection.name,
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "cargoId",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "sum": {
              "$sum": "$palletWidth"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "maxLineWidthEuro"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "maxLineWidthEuro": {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "sum",
          "input": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$maxLineWidthEuro",
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
  
          /*Weight only group*/
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleINDBULK}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightINDBULK]}},
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleFOODBULK}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightFOODBULK]}},
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleADR}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightADR]}},
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleINDLIQ}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightINDLIQ]}},
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleFOODLIQ}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightFOODLIQ]}},
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleANIMALS}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightANIMALS]}},
          
          /*Width, height, length in parent*/
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleSPECIAL}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightSPECIAL]}, height: {$lte: +tRuleMaxHeightSPECIAL}, width: {$lte: +tRuleMaxWidthSPECIAL}, clength: {$lte: +tRuleMaxLengthSPECIAL}},
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleHANG}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightHANG]}, height: {$lte: +tRuleMaxHeightHANG}, width: {$lte: tRuleMaxWidthHANG}, clength: {$lte: tRuleMaxLengthHANG}},
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleSPECIALHEIGHTS}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightSPECIALHEIGHTS]}, height: {$lte: tRuleMaxHeightSPECIALHEIGHTS}, width: {$lte: tRuleMaxWidthSPECIALHEIGHTS}, clength: {$lte: tRuleMaxLengthSPECIALHEIGHTS}},
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleNOTPALLETIZED}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightNOTPALLETIZED]}, height: {$lte: tRuleMaxHeightNOTPALLETIZED}, width: {$lte: tRuleMaxWidthNOTPALLETIZED}, clength: {$lte: tRuleMaxLengthNOTPALLETIZED}},
          {cargoType: {$eq: cRuleSPECIALLENGTHS}, $expr: {$lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 0.98]}, +tRuleMaxWeightSPECIALLENGTHS]}, height: {$lte: tRuleMaxHeightSPECIALLENGTHS}, width: {$lte: tRuleMaxWidthSPECIALLENGTHS}, clength: {$lte: tRuleMaxLengthSPECIALLENGTHS}},

          {cargoType: {$eq: cRulePALLETIZED}, maxLineWidthEuro: {$lte: totalWidth}}
        ],
    }},
    {
    $lookup: {
      from: Route.collection.name,
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "cargoId",
      as: "routes"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: User.collection.name,
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort : {
      date : -1
    }
  }
    ]);
    let fetchedCargos;
    if (pageSize && currentPage) {
      cargoQuery.skip(pageSize * (currentPage - 1)).limit(pageSize);
    }
    cargoQuery
      .then(documents => {
        fetchedCargos = documents;
        return Cargo.count();
      })
      .then(count => {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Cargos fetched successfully!",
          cargos: fetchedCargos,
          maxCargos: count
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
          message: "Fetching cargos failed!"
        });
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you only need a `$group` into an aggregation stage like this:

This query group all collections (using `_id: null`) and then `$sum` the value you want.

```
Cargo.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "maxLineWidthEuro ": {
        "$sum": "$palletWidth"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T3bmtXwes9y).

Additionally you can add a `$project` stage to output only value you want, like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tcyevpSm-zx)

Comment: Thanks for that. Inside Cargo.aggregate is a lookup for Pallets. Pallets collection have the field palletWidth!

Comment: Can you provide an example for both collections?

Comment: Is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zcfpc-Vr0NM) what are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks, we are close. Now i want to use that new field maxLineWidthEuro later in query. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

- `$lookup` with `$group` to get the sum of **palletWidth** of all documents`
- `$set` with `$getField` and `$arrayElemAt`  to get the sum as a number and not as value inside an array

```
db.cargo.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "pallete",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "sum": {
              "$sum": "$palletWidth"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "maxLineWidthEuro"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "maxLineWidthEuro": {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "sum",
          "input": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$maxLineWidthEuro",
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HylPXlGyoML)

Comment: Thank you for that. Your solution throws an error -> message: "Fetching cargos failed!". I have updated the question with final query.